# Number of Buckets in Amazon Free Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying out Amazon S3 for my file uploads and would like to store different buckets for development, test and production environments. In amazon documentation it was mentioned the following statement

> As part of the AWS Free Usage Tier,
>   you can get started with Amazon S3 for
>   free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers
>   receive 5 GB of Amazon S3 storage,
>   20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put
>   Requests, 15GB of data transfer in,
>   and 15GB of data transfer out each
>   month for one year.

Is there any limitation about the number of buckets. I mean if I have three buckets and If I use within the overall storage limit, will I be charged.

Answer (score 19):

Each account in AWS is limited to [100 buckets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?BucketRestrictions.html) -- even if you are paying the normal usage rates.

Buckets are not billable items in S3.

Answer (score 3):

If the limit of 100 is not enough you can create virtual folders in your buckets and structure your environment that way.